# Set pager default value in product form in adminhtml

Tags: magento2.3, uicomponent, pager, listing-component

I need to set some very high value as default in pager in product grid in adminhtml. Or to disable it whatsoever. 
Here's excerpt from my `product_listing.xml`

```
 <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
    <paging name="listing_paging">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sizesConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="value" xsi:type="string">66</item>
                    <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="66" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="string">66</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">66</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </paging>
</listingToolbar>
```

Neither of those work: nor value, nor option. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. Basically you need to do two things.

1) Create file `Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_listing.xml` and fill it that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
       <paging name="listing_paging">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sizesConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="value" xsi:type="number">5000</item>
                        <item name="maxSize" xsi:type="number">9999</item>
                        <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="5000" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="value" xsi:type="string">5000</item>
                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">5000</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </paging>
    </listingToolbar>
</listing>
```

2) Truncate table `ui_bookmark`. Or delete rows for specific user from it.

Answer (score 0):

You know that this change can break your view, right?

Having to load like 1k of products can result in memory overflow.

And you will be like wondering why this page is suddenly not working, consider talking to whoever you are doing it for, to change his mind :)

Comment: Yeah, I know that. But I need to do that nonetheless